# Определить версии установленных DAO и ADO на c#

Tags: c#, ado, dao

Для одного старого приложения (VBA) нужно проверить среду, где устанавливается программа. Т.е. нужно определить версии DAO (JET) и ADO, и установлены ли они вообще. Желатально на c#.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел, как можно определить версию ADO:

```
Type myType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("adodb.connection");
object myInst = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
Object vers = myType.InvokeMember("Version", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, myInst, null);
```

Вопрос по DAO остается открытым